# Not able to include reference to telerik dll VS 2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, telerik

I am updating my solution from Q1 2014 to Q3 2014 and after running the update wizard faced the error on VS 2013 SP 3:

> The name "ExtendedTextBox" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.MaskedTextBox;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Input".

When I go to the line where the errors occur I try to include the reference but nothing happens. 
[image: Reference tip from resharper]
I don't know why this happens. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in my answer? Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happens often to me that the wizard does that! The reason is not known, the official answer is  "there is some plugin installed in VS that affects the wizard".

```
1) manually cancel the old DLL
2) manually add the newest DLL
3) remove the line in the webconfig referringto the old DLL
4) remove the control, save the project, add back the control.
```

It shoud work.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried the 3) 4) part of your solution did not work. I will  follow your instruction in order. Will let you know on Monday I have taken few days off  from work :).